# PHP selecting images with specific width and building a grid

Tags: php, html, css

I'm having trouble with building a dynamic grid with PHP like this:
[image: grid]

I have an array containing images in various sizes, but always either 900 or 1800 in width.

Looks like this:

```
$images = array('img_1_900.jpg', 'img_2_900.jpg', 'img_3_1800.jpg', 'and so on');
```

Is there any smart way to do this? I'm kind of new to the PHP-thing, so any hints could be nice. Here's what i got so far:

```
 $img_count = count($images);
 $i = 1;
 while($i <= $img_count){
    list($width) = getimagesize($images[$i]);
    if($width = 1800){

    }
    $i++;
 }
```

I know this does nothing, but i simply don't know where to go from here. Hope some kind soul could help me a little along. I can't just float them, because they need to stay on line even after a resize, so some kind of table/table-div has to do it. I guess.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you want to achieve ? building a grid like above ?

Comment: If you have spacing between the images (900) it can't possibly match 1800.

Comment: No it's actually 1825, i just miswrote when making the image. And did the same in the question not to cause confusion. And yes, i want to achieve a grid as above.

Comment: Does the order matter? Are two rows of [900,900] acceptable?

Comment: I would like the images to come in the order of the array, to have a little say in how to arrange them, if it's possible. I don't know if it is though

Answer (score 0):

if your image array is allway build in the same way... and not getting sorted...

```
$i = 0;
$html = "<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='10' border=1>"
foreach($image as $img){
    if($i == 0)
        $html .= "<tr>";
    if($i < 2){
        $html .= "<td><img src='{$img}' /></td>";
        $i++;
    }
    if($i == 2){
      $html .= "</tr><tr>";
      $html .= "<td colspan=2><img src='{$img}' /></td>";
      $i = 0;
    }
}
echo $html;
```

Comment: I think he's drawing image not outputing HTML

Comment: oh ok, then i got him wrong... but why he has an array with images than ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't write full functional code for you but I'll write pseudo code

```
H_MARGIN = // horizontal margin between elements
V_MARGIN = // vertical margin

I_HEIGHT = // Image height

$ImgWidth = 1800 + H_MARGIN
$I1800 = // Number of 1800 images
$I900 = // Number of 900 images
$NRows = $I1800 + ceil($I900 /2);
$ImgHeight = $NRows * I_HEIGHT + V_MARGIN * ($NRows - 1);

 - Create $ImgWidth*$ImgHeight image
*- Blit 900 image then v_margin
 - If still a 900 blit next to the first
 - Else blit a 1800 then h_margin
 - While images left loop back to *
```